# Load image from plist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, plist

I am trying to input the link of the image on one of the plist <string>. 
What code should I add in to the implementation in order to load the image from that website and display in an UIImage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlFromPlist];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
[img drawInRect:someRect];
```